# How to bulk insert in PHP form textarea input?

Tags: php, bulkinsert

I want to create a form that should have a textarea as bulk input, then every row of that textarea can be store able as separate value in table via PHP.

What should I do?

Comment: Start building some HTML / PHP code and show that here if you get stuck.

Comment: Not a Good description.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try and add a bit of the code you tried, and where you got stuck in order to receive better answers. Often times you can find the answer to your question while writing it.

Comment: [I want to create a replica of The Empire State Building, but it's already been done.](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @AsheshKumar My description is good Vlad answered me.

Comment: @H.Clean He told "Try and add a bit of the code you tried, and where you got stuck in order to receive better answers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key piece of code is:

```
$values = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea_name']);
```

Don't forget to sanitize your inserts :)

Comment: what do you mean "sanitize"?!!!

Comment: You should read about sql injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I use Mysqli is it OK?!

Comment: It's great that you're using `MySQLi`, but you should really read about SQL injection. Go to the link I gave in my first comment and read both the question and answers.

Comment: for insert to database, data should be string. How I can convert it to string? I want to make each row to a record!

Answer (score -1):

I use this code

```
 $values = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea_name']);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ($values)");
```

data should be string.
How I can convert it to string? I want to make each row to a record! make my code compelet!